# Performance testing of a Silverlight application, using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, silverlight

I'm trying to test the performance of a `Silverlight` application using `JMeter`.

Can you please tell me is that possible?

If it is possible, can you please provide me the detailed steps to be followed.

Comment: @user246. That's definitely not a duplicate of mentioned question. This is about performance testing of Silverlight, which specific and I don't think JMeter can be applied here. JMeter, as far as I used it, is for testing backend services: HTTP, REST, queues, etc, while Silverlight is Microsoft's front-end technology like Adobe's Flash/Flex.

Comment: Similar to - http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8296/how-to-test-performance-and-load-for-silverlight-application-in-jmeter What information have you discovered via your own research?

Comment: Sorry, I chose the wrong link.

Answer (score 1):

In case of Silverlight application, you ll have to consider following points:

- JMeter basically tests performance of server by testing backend services. It has nothing to do with front end operations performed by AJAX or similar technologies.
- Silverlight is a front end technology and silverlight application mostly perform most of operation at front end.

So considering above points, if your Application is communicating with backend server; then you can definitely load test it (within scope of only those services).

Another challenge while testing silverlight applications is monitoring/recording of traffic. If JMeter fails to record application traffic to server then you can use Fiddler to assist you in this case.

In short, yes Silverlight application can be be tested via JMeter but there will be lot of limitations while doing the job.

Comment: You said that it is possible. can you please mention some brief steps to follow. my application is some what front end and back end. it has some database connectivity aslo.  Thank you

Comment: Assuming that you have previously worked with JMeter, steps will be similar to how you create scripts for a normal application. You can start with trying to record the given scenario and see if JMeter can record backend communication of your application. If that does not work then you can use fiddler to observe it. In that case you ll have to manually create scripts.

Comment: this might be helpful in case you need to work with fiddler https://support.winhost.com/kb/a986/how-to-troubleshoot-silverlight-ria-applications-using-fiddler.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Load Runner is an performance testing tool for testing WEB/WINDOW/Mobile Applications. HP Load Runner has Unlimited expiration date.

Load Runner provides lot of Protocols, it includes Silver light also.

Refer the Load Runner tutorial and make use of it.

http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/146500_c_silverlight_overview.htm